# How do I start a for loop with variables 001, 002, 003 in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How would I start a Powershell loop using variable numbers 001, 002, 003... instead of 1,2,3...?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the data to be string objects or integers?

Comment: The data is in integers

Comment: `1..3|%{$_.ToString('D3')}` or `1..3|%{'{0:D3}' -f $_}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "normal" intergers in the For staement and then format the variable to use in a string:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {'{0:d3}' -f $i}
```

[-f Format Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#format-operator--f)

or create an array of strings:

```
$arr = @('001', '002', '003', '004', '005')
foreach ($n in $arr) {$n}
```

[image]